# Не знаю как правильно построить SQL-запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sqlite, sqlite3

Доброго времени суток! Прошу помочь, делаю себе проект, бэкенд на nodejs +  sqlite. В проекте есть чат, без каналов, просто 1 на 1. В бэкенде очень слаб, поэтому не судите строго, может я неправильно таблицы построил.
Есть такие таблицы:

```
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  firstName varchar(30),
  lastName varchar(50),
  email varchar(150),
  phone varchar(12),
  address varchar(255),
  photo varchar(255),
  hash varchar(255),
  token varchar(255)
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  lastMessage varchar(255)
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chatUser (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  idChat integer,
  idUser integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (idChat) REFERENCES chat(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)`);
db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  idChat integer,
  idUser integer,
  text varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (idChat) REFERENCES chat(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)`);
```

В chatUser я заношу всегда только двух пользователей,т.е. текущего пользователя и того, с кем переписываюсь. И я пытаюсь сделать запрос, из которого я получаю список чатов текущего пользователя, с именем и фото человека, с кем переписываюсь, с id чата и последним сообщением из этого чата.
Получилось что-то такое:

```
db.all(`
  SELECT chatUser.idChat,
         user.firstName,
         user.lastName,
         user.photo,
         chat.lastMessage
  FROM user, chatUser, chat
  WHERE user.id = chatUser.idUser
  AND chat.id = chatUser.idChat
  AND user.id != ?
`, [id], function(error, chats) {
  ...
}
```

где id - это id текущего пользователя.
Это работало, пока я не зашел с другого пользователя, у которого вместо одного чата выводит еще лишних два. Помогите пожалуйста построить запрос корректно, я больше ничего не придумал.

Comment: `AND user.id != ?` вот тут у меня задергался глаз.. тут точно не должно быть `=` ?

Comment: @Darth ну мне нужно получить пользователя, с кем я чатюсь, вот я и проверяю пользователя != моему